# How to do a job every half an hour

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks

I want to do a job every half an hour. My application is based on Flask, and running on Windows.

Now I create a task for the job, using Windows scheduler service.

I want to know if there is another way I can do cyclic tasks using Flask’s built-in functions...

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is another way I can do [periodic] tasks using Flask’s built-in functions.

Being somewhat a minimalist microframework, I don't think Flask has or *ever will have* a **built-in** feature to schedule periodic tasks.

The customary way is what you have already done, you write some Flask code that can be called as an HTTP endpoint or a [script](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), then use a OS scheduling tool to execute it (e.g. [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) or [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on UNIX/Linux)

Otherwise, Flask works well with other specialized libraries that take care of this, like [Celery (periodic tasks)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) that takes care of those details and adds some features that may not be available  otherwise.

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-half-hour': {
        'task': 'tasks.your_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=30),
        'args': ('task_arg1', 'task_arg2')
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if this help, but I've been testing the schedule module and it's easy to use and it works well:

```
$pip install schedule
```

and this is a sample from the [official documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule):

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(30).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Hope this help =)